# ILO client for OSX

Tags: mac-osx, hp, ilo

over the last weeks I have been using ILO4 on my HP server quite extensively. Under OSX this seems to be a big pain however, I open the browser to get to the ILO interface, login, download a java applet, have to go to my security settings to really get this applet started and the click three warnings away before I actually get a connection.

Does anybody know whether accessing an ILO interface/remote console from OS-X can be done some better way? Is there a dedicated client that I could not find or did anybody manage to somehow locally install the java app?

Comment: I don't bother. The ILO java console should be so rarely needed it isn't worth the time to set up anything special. You should be doing normal administration through ssh (or PS remoting on Windows).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is quite common with Java-Applet-based management tools like iLo of older hardware.

I personally have setup a Windows XP VM with Java 6 installed (because some of my hardware only works with Java 6). This VM is in an isloated environment with its own firewall and extreme security.